# Where as part of SQL in for each - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to work on a Roll Solution for my cadet group which has monthly reporting.

I have the 2 following tables:

**Roll Table**

```
|id|roll_id|member_id|.....
```

**Rollmapping table**

```
|id|roll_date|roll_year|roll_month|roll_week|
```

I have the following to break down the ranks in the controller (This is just for the officers)

```
$officers = DB::table('roll')
    ->join('rollmapping', 'roll.roll_id' , '=', 'rollmapping.id' )
    ->join('members', 'members.id', '=', 'roll.member_id')
    ->join('rankmappings', 'members.rank', '=', 'rankmappings.id' )
    ->join('rollstatus', 'roll.status', '=', 'status_id')
    ->Select('members.*', 'roll.roll_id', 'rankmappings.*', 'rollstatus.status', 'roll.status')
    ->where('roll.roll_month', '=', $rollmonth)
    ->where('roll.status', '!=', 'A')
    ->where('members.rank', '<', 12 )
    ->orderby ('rankmappings.id')
    ->get();
```

This works perfect.

I can grab the roll month number using the following:

```
$rollmonth = Rollmapping::latest()->value('roll_month');
```

I don't want to repeat this code 5 times (as some months have 5 weeks)
Is it possible in the @foreach loop in the html table to define "$officers as $o where roll_week = 1" and so forth for each week?

I will have a HTML Table which will display like this

```
|         |Week 1 | Week 2| Week 3| week 4| Week 5|Total  |
|Officers |{count}|{count}|{count}|{count}|{count}|{total}|
|WO/TO    |{count}|{count}|{count}|{count}|{count}|{total}|
|NCO      |{count}|{count}|{count}|{count}|{count}|{total}|
|Cadets   |{count}|{count}|{count}|{count}|{count}|{total}|
|Total    |{total}|{total}|{total}|{total}|{total}|{total}|
```

If not is there a better way. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Eloquent relationships:

```
  $rolls = Roll::with(['rollmapping', 'members', 'rankmapping', 'rollstatus'])
    ->whereHas('members', function ($q) {
        $q->where('rank', '<', 12);
    })
    ->where('roll_month', $rollmonth)
    ->where('status', '!=', 'A')
    ->get();

$officers = $rolls->mapToGroups( function ($roll) { 
        return [
            $roll->roll_week => $roll
        ];
    });
```

That way you would have an array of weeks with an array of rolls under each.
Kinda like this.

```
[
1 => [
    'roll object1',
    'roll object 2',
],
2 => [
    'roll object3'
],
3 => [
    'roll object4'
],
4 => [
    'roll object5',
    'roll object6'
]
```

];

I think it would be better to bring in all the ranks in one query and sort in the table but based on the way you are doing it here is how you would populate the table with officers.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    @foreach($officers as $week => $roll)
        <th>Week {{$week}}</th>
    @endforeach
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Officers</td>
    @foreach($officers as $week => $roll)
        <td>{{$roll->sum()}}</td>
    @endforeach
    <td>{{$officers->sum(function ($week) { return $week->count(); })}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this as the table above

Comment: I'm not sure from your structure how you would determine what an Officer, Cadet or such is.

Comment: Based on the Rank ID "->where('members.rank', '<', 12 )", the code posted above is only for officers (have 1 for the other groups as well).